# FragmentContainerView shows incorrect attribute values

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment

When a FragmentContainerView parent activity is moved from one activity to another activity.  After returning the FragmentContainerView is not showing correct values like isVisible = false. Even if the fragment is being displayed on the screen.

private var knobViewsCloseListner:OnDismissDialogListener? =  object: OnDismissDialogListener{

```
    override fun handleDialogClose() {
      //calling the function for closing the fragment. 
    }

}
```

//above is the callback for closing the fragment with the normal

`fragment?.let { simv_nav_container.visibility = View.GONE fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit() }`

Comment: Some code maybe?

Comment: //but the problem is the FragmentContainerView is showing not visible  the simv_nav_container.isvisible shows false.  Whenever the activity is closed and moved to other activity and then migrated back.  At that particular time it shows the attribute false.